# cxf Magento SOAP request invalid: full operation name

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, cxf, apache-karaf

I'm trying to communicate to Magento's SOAP Api (v2, ws-i compliance enabled) using Apache cxf in Apache Camel running in Apache Karaf. The service implementation is generated using the "cxf-codegen-plugin" maven plugin.

The resulting request for the "login" operation looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:Magento">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:login>
            <ns:loginParam>
                <username>username</username>
                <apiKey>apikey</apiKey>
            </ns:loginParam>
        </ns:login>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, it should look like this (taken from soap-ui):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:Magento">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:loginParam>
            <username>username</username>
            <apiKey>apikey</apiKey>
        </ns:loginParam>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The key difference is that cxf generates a wrapper element around the contents of the soap body which is the full soap operation name (in this case: login).

Following the documentation of cxf (see http://cxf.apache.org/docs/http-binding.html, "Configuring the service"), it explicitly states: 
"... ServiceFactory to work in "wrapped" mode. This just means that our xml documents will be wrapped with the operation name..."

As far as I can tell, the service and the binding information is already generated not using "wrapped" mode.

Also, the according blueprint configuration of my camel cxf:endpoint explicitly disables "wrapped" service calls.

```
<camelcxf:cxfEndpoint ...>
    [...]
    <camelcxf:properties>
        [...]
        <entry key="wrapped" value="false" />
    </camelcxf:properties>
</camelcxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Furthermore, the generated port interface "MageApiModelServerWsiHandlerPortType" states that parameters should be passed "bare":

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

Now to confuse even more: If this client is used outside of Apache Karaf (in the IntelliJ debugger with a standalone Apache camel context for example), the soap request looks as expected and my api calls work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If yes, could you please add the solution here?